# Reset input form after the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

I'm facing a annoying issue. I can't find a way to clear the form after

the submit button is clicked in this react component . I tried pretty much everything.

is someone able to do this?

I tried window.local.reload, reset, and all other thing.

```
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import "./style.css";
import React from "react";

const About = () => {
  function sendEmail(e) { 
    e.preventDefault()
    document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").value=" " ;

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "",
        "",
        e.target,
        ""
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
  return (
    <div className="contact">
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{
          marginTop: "50px",
          width: "50%",
        }}
      >
        <h1 style={{ marginTop: "25px" }}>Contact Form</h1>
        <form className="form-style-6" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
          <label>name</label>
          <input  type="text" name="name" className="form-control" />

          <label>Email</label>
          <input  type="email" name="user_email" className="form-control"  />

          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea  name="message" rows="4" className="form-control" />
          <input
            type="submit"
            
            className="form-control btn btn-primary"
            style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}
            >
              
          </input>
        </form>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default About;
```

Comment: Are you trying to clear the form, or refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

just add an id for the textbox like:

```
  <input
    type="text"
    name="from_name"
    id="fieldName"
    className="form-control"
  />
```

and put this into the code:

```
...
     .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
    document.getElementById('fieldName').value = '';
  };
...
```